# C# server and Android Client

Tags: c#, android, eclipse, sockets, tcp

I'm working on two programs, one software Microsoft visual studio 2010 when I run a server and a second program : Eclipse ADT (ANDROID device development environment) in which I supposedly client. The goal is to establish a connection between SERVER in C# and Android CLIENT. It should not be a problem, I tried on TCP and UDP tried on, it falls on both object creation context (in TCP that falls on the object socket and UDP SOCKET falls DATAGRAM object creation), it seems to me the problem is: activitythread.performlaunchactivity (activitythread $ activityclientreco rd intent) line 2247

As I understand the problem is not in my code snippet but the SOCKET supplementation with software built into Eclipse, I tried to re-install, add the latest plugin. To your next question, I did permissions for Android device and internet. This I have no idea how to approach this problem which I am going for a month or more ..

In addition I'll add my code in android client :

```
   import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.net.InetAddress; 
import java.net.Socket; 
import java.net.UnknownHostException; 

import android.util.Log; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
private TextView txt;
private Button b;

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connectSocket("Hello");

        }
    });
} 

private void connectSocket(String a){ 

    try { 
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.8"); 
        Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting..."); 
        **Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 4444);** 

        String message = "1";

        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try { 
            Log.d("TCP", "C: Sending: '" + message + "'"); 
            out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true); 
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));                

            out.println(message);
            while ((in.readLine()) != null) {
                txt.append(in.readLine());
            }

            Log.d("TCP", "C: Sent."); 
            Log.d("TCP", "C: Done.");               

        } catch(Exception e) { 
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e); 
        } finally { 
            socket.close(); 
        } 

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        Log.e("TCP", "C: UnknownHostException", e); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        Log.e("TCP", "C: IOException", e); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }       
} 
}
```

and my server in C# :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class TestTCP
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            // use local m/c IP address, and 

            // use the same in the client


            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 11000);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 11000...");
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                              myList.LocalEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");
        m:
            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);

            char cc = ' ';
            string test = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
            for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
                cc = Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
                test += cc.ToString();
            }

            switch (test)
            {
                case "1":
                    break;


            }

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");


            /* clean up */
            goto m;
            s.Close();
            myList.Stop();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you may not run the `connecSocket` method in your UI thread. You have to do something like this:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Thread stackOverflow = new Thread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               connectSocket("Hello");

           }});

        stackOverflow.start();
    }
});
```

Otherwise you get this exception:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Secondly you must connect to the same port and interface where your server is listening:

```
IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
```

Should be the same address as the one you are using in your Android application:

```
IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.8");
```

And your Android application must connect to the same port where server is listening:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 11000);
```

Finally do not forget the Android permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And be careful with firewalls and things like that, they could also drop your connections.

Comment: Ok, so in C# i doesnt make any changes, but in android i putted the permissions, and change the ipAdrr to 10.0.0.8 and did the b.click thread like you does. Now, it doesnt work but it doesnt kick me out of the program. what to do ? there is no errors or something. thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: @BenTubul C# code must be changed to `IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.8");` and Android app to `Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 11000);` (Android app must connect to the same port and address where your C# server is listening) if you do that, it should work (at least it works for me) Do not forget, something between the android app and your C# server could drop connection attempts. Check if you have enabled firewalls or antivirus programs that could avoid the connections.

Comment: As you can see :
 http://sizmedia.com/my.php?i=m1mn2ruijnly.png 
this is wrong, the program doesnt let me run it.
Thank you again for your help dude :)

Comment: @BenTubul You must find out the IP address of the machine where you C# server is going to run. In Windows you can run this command from the `cmd.exe` console: `ipconfig /all` Look for your enabled interface and its IP address reading the entry called `Ip Address` Then use its value for C# `IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(YOUR_ENABLED_INTERFACE_ADDRESS);` and for Android: `InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(YOUR_ENABLED_INTERFACE_ADDRESS);`

Comment: when i type ipconfig it let me run on this ip but it doesnt work too(I mean with the new ip that i got from the cmd). Well, im hope you have power for me it very important for me i have big work for tommorow. :) thanks again !!

Comment: @BenTubul Did you try disabling your Windows Firewall? You could have one and perhaps you did not even realize.

Comment: I did it thank you very much you helpfull!!!!!! love you@@@@@@!@!#@!$%$@#^#^@#%^!#$^!#$ wowowwowoowowww i worked for it like a month !!!

Comment: @BenTubul if you mark the answer as right you would make me really happy. :P